# Is there a single word equivalent of *anímicamente* (from Spanish)?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

There's a succinct way to talk about mood, as an adverb, in Spanish.  For example,

> Yes, I've always realized there's a certain amount of poverty in the U.S., but now, living here for the past two months, I'm finding that seeing all the poverty right here is really affecting me *anímicamente*.

The best I've got so far is **moodwise** which of course sounds awful.

Yes, okay, I could regroup and say

> it's really affecting my mood.

Second example.

> No está enfermo, pero anímicamente anda mal.

He's not sick, but his mood is not good.  (Closest I can get -- not satisfying.)

But if there's a way to say this without regrouping, I'd like to know what it is.

Do we have an adverb for that in English?

Comment: '. . . affecting me _unfavourably_' He's not sick, but he's _unfavourably_ disposed. It's a bit dated but it's the best I can do.

Comment: Wiktionary licenses 'dispositionally' in the sense 'moodwise', but this sounds almost as bad. People would say '... is really getting me down'.

Answer (score 1):

**[Emotionally](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/emotionally)**

> In a way that relates to a person's emotions.
>   In a manner characterized by intense feeling.

*Oxford Dictionaries*

For example,

> Yes, I've always realized there's a certain amount of poverty in the U.S., but now, living here for the past two months, I'm finding that seeing all the poverty right here is really affecting me ***emotionally.***

You would then rely on context to get the emotion the person is feeling.

Comment: It's a perfect fit, I agree.  But I'm looking for a word that will convey that meaning, just as well as *moodwise* does, without having to rely on building up a context to show how to interpret the word.